# how to restore sqlite dump file to sqlite database using java?

Tags: sqlite, restore, java

I generated dump file from java using .dump command so my back-up is ready now I want to restore it to once again so can anyone help me how to restore?

In stackoverflow I got this but nothing restore from this..[backup-and-restore-sqlite-from-disk-to-memory-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548026/backup-and-restore-sqlite-from-disk-to-memory-in-java)

so how to restore this file?

Comment: Java has no `.dump` command. If you've used `.dump`, it was in the `sqlite3` command-line tool, which has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: @CL..ya I generated dump file in sqlite3 but generated dump file does not containing "Drop Table if exist" statement as it was in the SQLite manager generated file so can you help me for this?

Comment: `sqlite3`'s dump file is intended to recreate everything in an *empty* database.

Comment: @CL..then I want dump file which restores in existing file then? like SQLiteManager does?

Comment: Just delete the database file first.

Comment: @CL., no i don't want to delete update existing records with newly added..

Comment: This is not called "backup"/"restore". You want to synchronize two databases.

Comment: @CL..no when my copy of database that is backup in my pc and i want to update with the newly added record.. i used this application for synchronize database..but both the tables is same

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JDBC with Java, have a look at [sqlite-jdbc
 by xerial](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc). They added the backup and restore API of sqlite a while ago.

I use this together with an sqlite in memory-database for higher performance and regularly backup to a file.

You can use it like this:

```
// Use this connection string for an in memory-database
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");

connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("restore from database.db");
connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("backup to database.db");
```